Out of memory Requested array size exceeds VM limit Error occuring while saving a Byte array to DB
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit  
   at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3745 undefined)  
   at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:169 undefined)  
   at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:772 undefined)  
   at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:248 undefined)  
   at java.base/java.util.Arrays.toString(Arrays.java:4988 undefined)  
   at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.extractLoggableRepresentation(PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.java:63 undefined)  
   at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.extractLoggableRepresentation(PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.java:26 undefined)  
   at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:70 undefined)  
   at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.converter.AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter$1.bind(AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter.java:88 undefined)  
   at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:280 undefined)  
   at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:275 undefined)  
   at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:39 undefined)  
   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2879 undefined)  
   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3176 undefined)  
   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3699 undefined)  
   at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:90 undefined)  
   at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604 undefined)  
   at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478 undefined)  
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356 undefined)  
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:50 undefined)  
   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1418 undefined)  
   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1504 undefined)  
   at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1561 undefined)  
   at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1529 undefined)  
   at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:168 undefined)  
   at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76 undefined) 

The above error is occurring while saving the below entity
@Table(name = "FILE_DATA")
public class FileData
{

    @Id
    @Column(name= "ID")
    private Long id;
    

    @Convert(converter = CustomArrayCompressionConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "CONTENT")
    private byte[] content;
}

Db Datatypes for
TABLE [FILE_DATA] -
[ID] [numeric](10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
[CONTENT] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.extractLoggableRepresentation(PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.java:63) 

Here the huge byte array is being converted to String. So I need to exclude this from logging.
Issue was occurring while saving a 2 GB byte array as 2 parts of 1.7GB and 300MB. Heap size is set to 14GB.
I tried using regex filter in Log4j properties, it omits the byte array from Log file, but it's still converting this byte array to string.
I need to omit this byte array or give a custom name like 'Huge array logging' while logging byte array/
I've seen a solution using custom UserType in Hibernate trace values of statement parameters except blobs, but it cannot be used as I am using a custom  AttributeConverter (CustomArrayCompressionConverter - to compress and decompress before inserting to db)
Is there any other approach to achieve this?

You need to turn of logging of SQL parameters.
Set org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind logger to something above TRACE.
It is possible to override extractLoggableRepresentation for PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor by registering custom version of PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor in custom dialect.
Note that class was renamed to PrimitiveByteArrayJavaType in latest
(mine is 6.5.2) version of hibernate-core.

Turning off will work. But I need the  logging of SQL parameters.

Why? If you use that log for something except debugging you doing something strange.

In production environments, immediate access to these parameters helps us quickly identify and resolve bugs without the overhead of reproducing the issue in a debug setting. So I need the SQL parameter information

In the issue you linked there is also a solution based on logging filtering (in that case, it used a RegexFilter for log4j2). Which loggin framework are you using? Perhaps you can try a similar approach.

@DarkKnight There is nothing you can do then, unless you wiling to do runtime code manipulation. That String is generated before it passed to logger. See org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.BasicBinder#bind(java.sql.CallableStatement, J, java.lang.String, org.hibernate.type.descriptor.WrapperOptions)

@Francesco Poli
I am using Log4j2. I have tried RegexFilter. But the error occuring here happens before logging happens. It happens while we are converting byte array to Loggable form, in this case it is being converted to string.

@talex moved to Codidact
runtime code manipulation can be done. I have seen this BasicBinder#bind method you commented. The BasicBinder classes are Final so we cant extend  and in the 'AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter.getBinder(JavaTypeDescriptor javaTypeDescriptor)' BasicBinder  is returned in all SqlTypeDescriptor. So I think CustomBasicBinder also wont work. Pls Correct me if Im wrong

@DarkKnight which Hibernate version are you using?

@Francesco Poli 5.4.0.Final

@DarkKnight you may try to create custom dialect and replace PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor with custom implementation.

@talex moved to Codidact Created a Custom Dialect and replaced PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor with custom implementation. It worked. Post it as an Answer. I will Accept it. Thank you for helping
